# Circular Hough Transform using gradient

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm trying to implement hough transform algorithm to detect circles in a gray scale image. 
I ran edge detector and used the gradient's orientation at each point in order to get the line on which the radius lies.
Then, I've tried to accumulate votes for each circle with center (cX,cY) and radius r:

```
% run edge detection on image
Edges = edgeDetect(img);
% initialize accumulator matrix
Acc = zeros(imgRows, imgCols, maxR);    
% get indices of edge points
edgePoints = find(Edges);
% get number of edg points
numOfEdges = size(edgePoints);

for currEdge = 1 : numOfEdges

    % get edge cartesian coordinate
    [eY eX] = ind2sub([imgRows, imgCols], edgePoints(currEdge));        
    % find gradient's direction at this point
    theta = Directions(eY, eX);

    for r  = minR : maxR

        % find center point according to polar representation of circle
        cX = round( eX - r*cos(theta) );
        cY = round( eY - r*sin(theta) );

        % check if (cX,cY) is within image's boundaries
        if 1 <= cX && cX <= imgCols && 1 <= cY && cY <= imgRows

            % found a circle with (cX,cY) as center and r as radius
            Acc(cY, cX, r) = Acc(cY, cX, r) + 1; % increment matching counter

        end            
    end        
end
```

However, the maximum value in accumulator (Acc) is 10 - so I guess something's wrong with the way I count circles. I've tried debugging it but could not see where the problem is...
Any ideas what could be wrong? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What did you expect to find? how is 10 a bad value for a maximum?

Comment: Each entry in Acc says how many edge points are on the perimeter of a circle with center (cX,cY) and radius r. Therefore, 10 edge points on perimeter is too sparse

Comment: There could be some uncertainty in both radius and center. Try `imagesc(sum(Acc,3))` to visualize the result. If noise was the problem, you should see clearly identifiable clusters.

Comment: I ran imagesc(sum(Acc,3)), and got a tiny red rectangle at top-left corner (image can be found in this link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47588150/imagesc.png). 
AFAIK, it means that there is no noise. 
Is there anything else that can be learnt from this plot? thank you!

Comment: It means that there is only one circle that has bee found, and that it's supposedly at (1,1). It's difficult to say more without knowing the original image.

Comment: I see. Well, it means that something is indeed wrong, since there are 5 circles in the image. Here is a link for it : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47588150/balls4.tiff. 
If it matters, I store the image as [0,...,1] double matrix:
>> img = imread('balls4.tiff');
>> img = double(img)/255;